# How can I see the names of "local" git branches of a repo from the repo server

Tags: client, localhost, git-branch, git-bash, git-clone

How can I see the names of "local" git branches of a cloned repo from the repo server?  I have 8-10 developers and I want to insure they are using branch naming standards on their local machines.. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is what I was explaining in "[Definition of “downstream” and “upstream”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)":

> The DVCS (*Distributed* Version control System) twist is: you have no idea what downstream actually is, beside your own repo relative to the remote repos you have declared.
>
> - you know what upstream is (the repos you are pulling from or pushing to)
> - you don't know what downstream is made of (the other repos pulling from or pushing to your repo).

You cannot see the downstream repos and their branches: they can see you. Not the reverse.

What you can do is setup a [pre-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) which would enforce a branch-naming policy and reject any push to a branch not matching that policy.

See for instance [this hook](https://github.com/digitalplaywright/hudson-git-policies/blob/master/hooks/pre-receive):

```
# if this is a branch with a prefixed name...
if echo $ref | grep -q "^refs/heads/.*-" ; then
...
else # branch does not have a prefix on the form 'prefix-*'
  echo "$ref is not a valid branch name. Please consult the naming conventions."
  exit 1;
fi
```